# On enabling Network adapter, Autoconfiguration IP address getting set

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-programming, wmi

I am developing an application for Windows Vista and 7 in Visual Studio C++, in which I have to assign static IP address to a network card and establish a connection. For this, I am entering the Ip values in registry along with setting the Enable DHCP value to 0. Then I need to disable and then enable the network card for these values to take effect. For this, I am using "INetConnectionManager" in the following code:

```
  CoInitialize(0);
  typedef void (__stdcall * PNcFreeNetconProperties)(NETCON_PROPERTIES* pProps);
  HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary(L"netshell.dll");
  if (!hmod) 
    return false;

  LPNcFreeNetconProperties NcFreeNetconProperties =
    (LPNcFreeNetconProperties)GetProcAddress(hmod, "NcFreeNetconProperties");

  if (!NcFreeNetconProperties )
    return false;

  INetConnectionManager * pMan = 0;

  HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ConnectionManager,
                  0,
                  CLSCTX_ALL,
                  __uuidof(INetConnectionManager),
                  (void**)&pMan);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hres))  
  {    
      IEnumNetConnection * pEnum = 0;
      hres = pMan->EnumConnections(NCME_DEFAULT, &pEnum);
     if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
     {
         INetConnection * pCon = 0;
         ULONG count;
         bool done = false;
         while (pEnum->Next(1, &pCon, &count) == S_OK && !done)
         {
             NETCON_PROPERTIES * pProps = 0;
             hres = pCon->GetProperties(&pProps);
             if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
             {
                 if (wcscmp(pProps-pszwDeviceName, AdapterName) == 0)
                 {
                     if (bEnable)
                         result = (pCon->Connect() == S_OK);
                     else
                         result = (pCon->Disconnect() == S_OK);
                     done = true;
                 }

                 NcFreeNetconProperties(pProps);
              }
              pCon->Release();
         }
         pEnum->Release();
     }
    pMan->Release();
  }
  FreeLibrary(hmod);
  CoUninitialize();
```

It's disabling and enabling the network card very well, **BUT the autoconfiguration IPv4 values are getting set instead of the static values in the registry. This strangely works properly for DHCP connection but not for static connection.**

**NOTE: I even tried SetIfEntry for it, but it fails to disable or enable Network Card.**

Please suggest where I am doing wrong or anything I am missing.

Comment: *Waaay* too many levels of nesting for this code to be readable.

Comment: I don't know if that's the right way to go about it; you may want to have a look at the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI class and see if it supports what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Luke I found about INetConnectionManager from this msdn [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ad3ae21d-515d-4f67-8519-216f1058e390).Also i can see the network card getting disabled and enabled by it. But not the values getting set. **I also wanted to ask you is there anything ELSE required apart from editing registry and disabling-enabling Network card for setting static IP values???** Is this the same way windows os handle this task??

Comment: @ Cody Gray I have edited the code again. Hope you find it readable. I am new here so couldn't do it right first time. Kindly tell me if there is something i am missing here to set static ip values.

Comment: I figured out the problem!!!                                          First thing, there is nothing wrong with this code to disable/enable network adapter. Only thing is it needs admin login. For that I've given UAC permission to the app from project properties.                      I was going wrong in setting the registry values for it before disabling/enabling network adapter(didn't handle REG_MULTI_SZ value properly). I fixed that now. It works fine in windows xp, vista and 7.                                                               Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddIPAddress:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi!                                                                                I have tried using that before also. AddIPAddress will only add the IP Address and the Subnet Mask in the network table maintained by the OS. But these values will not be configured for networking(unless the one being used currently fails to provide a net connection). Hence I had to go with registry editing.                    Regards

Answer (score 0):

Does INetConnectionManager supported on Windows VISTA and Win7? I have implemented the same code what you have written here but I get access denied for pCon->Connect when application runs on non admin login. Therefore, it looks like that we need to elevate the com object using COM Moniker.

Regards
IP_Telephony

Comment: @ IP_Telephony- INetConnectionManager requires admin login to work. You are right in this regard. I've given UAC access to my application from Project Properties->Manifest File. Then it will work in win vista and 7 also.