# Enable/Disable DHCP on a network interface via Win32 api

Tags: windows, api

i'm looking for a way to enable or disable dhcp on a network interface via win32 api.
actually i solve this by using wmi but i would like to do this via win32 api because i would like to workaround corrupted wmi's.

i found a thread where they do this via registry api: [On enabling Network adpater, Autoconfiguration IP address getting set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967422/on-enabling-network-adpater-autoconfiguration-ip-address-getting-set) but is this the only way to achieve?

cheers, ceth

Comment: Direct registry approaches are going to be fragile. WMI is probably the only sane way to do it, unless there is a non-registry API, which I'm not aware of, unless it's this API:  SCAPI (setup and configuration API).  I know how to do that in Delphi thanks to this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/ You might check it and find the names of the SCAPI functions from there.

Comment: so how would you do this with this library? i found a big amount of win32 api function mappings. but the only dhcp related functions i found are the ones from the dhcp client/server api which has no functions for enable/disable dhcp on network adapters.

Comment: You want to find the Setup API that will enumerate a class ID for network adapters. Then you want to enumerate configuration properties for that ethernet adapter. That's all I know. Figure it out yourself!

Comment: Is shelling out to `netsh.exe` an option?

Comment: i finally did it with wmi and shelling out netsh.exe as a backup if wmi is not working.

the way over the win32 api is quite too unhandy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally did it with wmi and shelling out netsh.exe as a backup if wmi is not working. the way over the win32 api is quite too unhandy..